# Sanitize strings expected to be in UTF-8, but which sometimes are not, in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17

We are loading SQLite DBs, into PostgreSQL.

SQLite expects UTF-8 strings, but is rather lenient, not enforcing UTF-8-ness.
While PostgreSQL is strict, and will fail the transaction with such strings.
During tests, once in a while, invalid strings do actually happen, so we must do something.

I'd like to detect such strings, and replace the invalid *sequences* with U+FFFD, in C++.
I've looked a little into `std::codecvt`, but all examples are from one encoding to another,
not sanitizing within a single (UTF-8) encoding, and the cppreference.com doc isn't crystal clear to me either...

Do note that the plan is to record those anomalies, so that data-managers can go back, after-the-fact, and manually review the strings. In case they do recognize the native (non-UTF-8) encoding of the original strings, to update the automatically sanitize strings (that contains U+FFFD replacement characters). Thus, solutions that are pure SQLite or PostgreSQL are probably not possible (although I'd be happy to read about those too, if any).

I've found code that does it *manually*, but before I go too far into that rabbit hole,
is there std-C++17 code that could achieve the above? Portable solution needed (MSVC and GCC).

PS: I can detect a non-UTF-8 strings, since `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>::from_bytes` throws in that case, but that does not give me the sanitized string, nor does it tell me where the *bad* sequences are.

Comment: How do you define an invalid UTF-8 string? Is it just code units that do not fit the requirements of UTF-8, or do you want to ensure that the code point sequence that the string encodes is valid Unicode (ie: doesn't contain invalid codepoints), or something more?

Comment: you might find this useful: https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Comment: I usually use libicu for Unicode stuff in C++. It has functions that would make this pretty easy

Comment: @NicolBolas Whatever makes PostgreSQL happy. Which I suspect are both valid-sequence and valid-codepoint. libicu is too heavyweight for my needs. Since std-C++17 does not seem to have what I need, I'm trying out https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp as suggested by @AlanBirtles, which seems to have a ready-made `utf8::replace_invalid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp, as suggested by Alan Birtles, since UTFCPP is well documented, and appears stable. That library is header-only, and I wrapped it as shown below.

```cpp
bool isUtf8(std::string_view text, size_t* p_invalid_offset) {
    size_t local_invalid = 0;
    size_t& invalid = p_invalid_offset? *p_invalid_offset: local_invalid;
    invalid = ::utf8::find_invalid(text);
    return invalid == std::string_view::npos;
}
std::string sanitizeUtf8(std::string_view text) {
    return ::utf8::replace_invalid(text);
}
```

Also, since invalid UTF-8 text is rather rare in my case, instead of using `sanitizeUtf8()` systematically, I instead do:

```cpp
size_t invalid = 0;
if (!isUtf8(sv, &invalid)) {
    std::string sanitized{ sv.substr(0, invalid) };
    sanitized += sanitizeUtf8(sv.substr(invalid));
    // use sanitized
} else {
    // use sv directly
}
```

Which speeds things up, since `isUtf8()` is faster than  `sanitizeUtf8()`, and again the frequency of non-UTF-8 is very low in my case.

Performance-wise, I get around 270 and 140 MB/s on Win10 MSVC2019 (for `isUtf8()` and `sanitizeUtf8()` respectively); 1'100 and 250 MB/s on RedHat7 GCC9 (older machine though)

PS: For completeness, the PostgreSQL error on non-UTF-8 is [*character_not_in_repertoire* `"22021"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).